# Can't set text-area to width: 100% using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

I'm trying to set a textarea in rails to be the width of its container.  I've tested that the css is working on the textarea.

Form View:

```
<%= form_tag("/pages/thank_you") do %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group">
              <%= text_area_tag :message, nil, class: 'form-control text-area-wide', placeholder: 'Enter Message' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag 'Send Message', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  <% end %>
```

CSS:

```
.text-area-wide {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you should use the col classes in place of fixed width to keep responsive design change the col to col-md-12

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="input-group">
              <%= text_area_tag :message, nil, class: 'form-control text-area-wide', placeholder: 'Enter Message' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think it's a good instinct to think first about the width of the col class. My question could have been more clear. And your answer led me to the correct one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The limit on the width of the text area in this case was the .input-group div.  Setting the width of that div with css will change the width of the text-area.